# Node.js - Joi schema: Check req.value & ip not working

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I have this joi schema to validate email and password that was sent via body as json. In addition I now want to check the ip address. I tried it like below but I get this:

```
{
    "isJoi": true,
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "details": [
        {
            "message": "\"ip\" is required",
            "path": [
                "ip"
            ],
            "type": "any.required",
            "context": {
                "key": "ip",
                "label": "ip"
            }
        }
    ],
    "_object": {
        "email": "loremlipsum02@abc.at",
        "password": "kyuser2923?"
    }
}
```

Here my joi schema in routehelpers.js

```
const Joi = require('joi');

module.exports = {
    validateSignup: (schema) => {
        return (req, res, next) => {
            const result = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
            if (result.error) {
                return res.status(400).json(result.error);
            }

            if (!req.value) { req.value = {}; }
            req.value['body']= result.value;
            next();
        }
    },
    schemas: {
        signupSchema: Joi.object().keys({
            email: Joi.string().email().required(),
            password: Joi.string().required(),
            ip: Joi.string().ip({
              version: [
                'ipv4',
                'ipv6'
              ],
              cidr: 'required'
            }).required()
        })
    }
}
```

When I insert in my controller:

```
const curIP = req.ip;
console.log('IP: '+curIP);
```

I do get the ip in the console:

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:4002/
IP: 127.0.0.1
```

But how in addition can I validate the ip from the server requesting a signup?

I suppose it is because it is checking everything in req.value.body . But how do I need to alter validateSignup: (schema) to also check the ip that is requesting signup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to match `ip` property in `body` while it's a property of `req` object.

Try:

```
const result = Joi.validate(Object.assign(req.body, { ip: req.ip }), schema);
```

Although I think better approach would be using a library like [proxy-addr](https://github.com/jshttp/proxy-addr). That is going to extract correct client IP even when your server runs behind a reverse proxy.

Comment: pls, im using similar code, but my post request is getting empty parameters.